# Auto-completion during human verification on mobile

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, design

When typing the captcha for human verification on a mobile device, text completion is allowed on the input element which makes this already annoying (but necessary) task more annoying.

Here is a link for [turning auto-completion off](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/autocomplete-off/).

Comment: Isn't the input box generated directly by the reCaptcha script?

Comment: Still then, some jQuery magic could change that input box?

Comment: @Arjan: Still seems like something they should complain directly to reCapctha about. I mean, the example one on their website has spell-checking and auto-completion set to off in the HTML, so they're obviously aware of the need to do that.

Comment: Strange: the problem doesn't occur on http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore

Comment: You're right, @animuson. Even more: [the HTML](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha) actually is `<input style="..." autocomplete="off">`. (And the same page on Mobile, right?)

Comment: If the mobile device is iOS, you might need `autocorrect="off"`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is [meta-tag:status-completed], or maybe [meta-tag:status-norepro]. The only SE site I know of that's [still using reCaptcha v1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305988/recaptcha-v1-is-shutting-down-on-march-31-but-sede-still-uses-it) is SEDE, and the `autocomplete="off"` attribute seems to be present there. And reCaptcha v1 is shutting down in one week, anyway.