# reCaptcha v1 is shutting down on March 31, but SEDE still uses it

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, captcha

According to this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244726/269001), I thought the new recaptcha API was used network-wide.
Though today, when going to [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) (which for whatever reasons never recognized me automatically), I got this message instead of a usable captcha image.

> [image]
> V1 Unsupported
> Please direct siteowner to [g.co/recaptcha/upgrade](https://g.co/recaptcha/upgrade)

(Doing a second try doesn't show this message anymore, and the *recaptcha v1* works as intended.)

---

According to [the linked page](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#what-happens-to-recaptcha-v1), the reCAPTCHA v1 API will stop working on March 31, 2018:

> #### What happens to reCAPTCHA v1?
>
> **Any calls to the v1 API will not work after March 31, 2018.** Starting in November 2017, a percentage of reCAPTCHA v1 traffic will begin to show a notice informing users that the old API will soon be retired.
>
> Most websites around the world have already switched to reCAPTCHA v2, where humans pass effortlessly. With our advanced risk analysis engine, reCAPTCHA v2 can effectively separate humans from bots and always stay ahead of the attackers.
>
> If your site still uses reCAPTCHA v1, please upgrade to reCAPTCHA v2 immediately. We no longer support reCAPTCHA v1. Any calls to the v1 API will not work after March 31, 2018. Please register a new key and upgrade to v2.

I'm really hoping this will not take [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514) to fix, because we've only got three and a half weeks left!

Comment: SEDE is not an actual part of the network, and often gets forgotten for things like this since it's an open source project not completely maintained by us. (That's also why your session for the rest of the network doesn't work on SEDE - completely separate and disjoined auth system there.)

Comment: @animuson ah I didn't know about that. Then should I contact someone else or is this the correct place anyway?

Comment: Here is a good place. The new code still has to be deployed to our instance whenever it gets updated.

Comment: FWIW, I just got the same message, and it turns out that entering "V1 UNSUPPORTED" in the text box *does* pass the test. :D

Comment: For me nearly the same, but now I also get an accurate date when the shutdown will happen. It's March 31 this year. https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/images/v1_unsupported.png

Comment: I'm afraid we're out of luck... Tim Stone appears to be no longer involved with SEDE, and there's nobody else to change the required code. Likely SEDE will just shut down at some point.

Comment: It would be nice if they could use the same captcha as on all other sites where you just need to check a checkbox and don't have to type anything.

Comment: Doom da doom doom doooom. I'll fix the code this week, so presuming someone can deploy things will magically work out

Comment: @TimStone Thank you, but could you maybe consider open-sourcing the SEDE code if you're permitted to, to prevent this sort of thing from becoming an issue again?

Comment: @IanKemp Data Explorer [has always been open source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer)

Comment: @DonaldDuck That's exactly what they now *have* to do.

Comment: @TimStone week later, curious to know if you fixed anything?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, I did the replacement, I'll put out the pull request later and add an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A fix is [merged](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/86) [now](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/87) and seems to be live (thanks Nick!)

Comment: I might look into the invisible recaptcha later to avoid the whole submit -> captcha -> resubmit thing later, but there's a whole list of things that need cleaning up in that codebase

Comment: I came here just to say that the new capcha is AWESOME and so much easier than the old one.

Comment: [Nope](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308692/data-se-recaptcha-error). What went wrong? Any idea? :/