# data.SE recaptcha error

Tags: bug, data-explorer, recaptcha

Currently data.stackexchange.com is unusable for anonymous users, with the following error message:

[image]

I think I'm supposed to tell you to go to http://g.co/recaptcha/upgrade. Either than or I'm secretly not human.

The answer at a [a previous bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305988/recaptcha-v1-is-shutting-down-on-march-31-but-sede-still-uses-itck!)) claims it was fixed before the shutdown, seemingly not so.

Comment: This is supposed to be fixed already...

Comment: According to comments on the older report, it was fixed then looks like the fix got reverted somehow

Comment: Hmm, [status-norepro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SoZk.png)?

Comment: Oh damn, it turns out chrome restored the tab and helpfully cached everything. Everytime with the caching.

Comment: *laughs [cachedly](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)*

Comment: I have reproduced it a couple of days ago. Reloading the captcha makes everything work.

Comment: Huh. Forgot how annoying cache can be.